# Invert effect if it is mobile

Tags: css, mobile, media-queries

Currently, the WordPress stylesheet has this effect on images:

```
.course-hover .x-bg>.x-bg-layer-lower-image {
    filter: grayscale(1);
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out
}
.course-hover:hover .x-bg>.x-bg-layer-lower-image {
    filter: grayscale(0);
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out
}
```

Which is exactly what we want for a desktop view, however on mobile it shows the images in grayscale the whole time.

Is there a way to have the mobile not apply the grayscale?

On another post, I did see:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  body {
    background-color: red;
    overflow-y: hidden;
  }
}
```

But I'm unsure if this would work on a WordPress stylesheet?

Comment: It would make rather little sense to applies this in general first, and then try to un-do it in a media query for smaller devices - why not the other way around to begin with? BUT - the screen size of a device tells you rather little about whether it actually has/supports any sort of pointer device ...

Comment: Are you suggesting using something like a media query so if they have a mouse apply the effect?

Comment: Would this work?

@media not (pointer: none) {
.course-hover .x-bg>.x-bg-layer-lower-image {
 filter: grayscale(1);
 transition: all .3s ease-in-out
}
.course-hover:hover .x-bg>.x-bg-layer-lower-image {
 filter: grayscale(0);
 transition: all .3s ease-in-out
}
}

Comment: Could you make a minimal reproducible example so I can see what exact effect you have implemented?

Comment: Let me know if this answers your question, and then I can put it in an answer. https://codepen.io/vince1444/pen/XWoLJxa

Comment: As an answer I had to use "@media screen and (min-device-width: 600px)" to get it to work, The "@media hover" had no effect at all on either android or apple. I know its not ideal as it prevents the effect for smaller monitors and unique devices, however this is a trade off we are happy with. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could use [the hover CSS media feature](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/hover) to target only devices that have a mouse to hover with. And apply the grayscale to those devices only.

Your CSS should look like this :

```css
@media (hover: none) {
  /* when hover is NOT supported */
  .course-hover .x-bg>.x-bg-layer-lower-image {
    filter: grayscale(1);
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out
  }
  .course-hover:hover .x-bg>.x-bg-layer-lower-image {
    filter: grayscale(0);
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out
  } 
}
```

This CSS feature is widely supported now, [see canIuse](https://caniuse.com/css-media-interaction)

Comment: While this is a cool approach, why not just use a regular media query? You're excluding IE with this approach.

Comment: @Vince indeed, IE doesn't support this. But the usage for IE is now really low and will keep getting lower. Depending on the use case, I would consider using this approach over a regular media query that might not target the right devices. Like tablets with wide screens and most smartphones in horizontal view.